# aptitude install apach derby ij

Tags: 12.04, command-line, package-management, java, database

I see a similar question here:

> Question How do I connect to toursdb of Derby database using ij in
>   Ubuntu How do I connect to toursdb of Derby database using ij in
>   Ubuntu I have Ubuntu , I have installed javadb(Derby) at
>   /usr/share/javadb, How do I connect to toursdb of Derby database using
>   ij in Ubuntu

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862996

but can't find much information on installing [ij](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/ij_toc.html).  I just want to install ij.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will help but look at [this](http://yumsnotes.blogspot.com/2010/07/setting-up-and-accessing-derby-db-in.html)